VSCode setting "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor"NOT WORK IN BRAND NEW WINDOW
"workbench.editorAssociations": {   
  "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor" 
},

My settings.json has the above settings.
If my VSCODE program HAS launched (with or without a tab), it works fine - markdown automatically starts in preview mode.
However, if I don't have any VSCODE program running (for example, reboot computer and run VSCODE for the first time), it goes into edit mode anyway.
(I've spent all afternoon searching google. I haven't seen any useful info.)

Probably a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197374

thanks,looks same same. I can't imagine it took me so long
